# Finding the root of a complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

I have a complex number $8-6 i$ . I have to find the square root . I did all the steps and I got $\pm(-3+i)$. I also got $\pm(3-i)$. On squaring I am getting the same $8-6 i$, but what is the right square root . Please someone point out my mistake.

Comment: $+(-3+i) = -(3-i)$ You wrote the same thing twice

Answer (score 1):

$$\sqrt{8-6i}=\sqrt{\left|8-6i\right|e^{\arg\left(8-6i\right)i}}=$$
$$\sqrt{\sqrt{8^2+6^2}e^{-\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{6}{8}\right)i}}=\sqrt{\sqrt{100}e^{-\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)i}}=$$
$$\sqrt{10e^{-\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)i}}=\left(10e^{-\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)i}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}=$$
$$\sqrt{10}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)i}=$$
$$\sqrt{10}\cos\left(-\frac{1}{2}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)\right)+\sqrt{10}\sin\left(-\frac{1}{2}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)\right)i=3-i$$